# how to add subviews next to each other in code?

Tags: ios, macos, object

I am trying to add subviews to window that will be placed next to each other, on window resize they will be resized and stay next to each other, I am adding the subviews in code using

```
NSWindow* window;
[window.contentFrame addSubView:newView];
```

i would like to do so with the constraints API:

```
contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:prevView
                                                                     attribute:?
                                                                     relatedBy:?
                                                                        toItem:newView
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                    multiplier:?
                                                                      constant:?]];
```

Comment: Sir, this is objective-C not swift..and what do you mean for next to each other? Near the next?

Comment: horizontally next to each other, that each subview is placed right next to its previous view

Comment: You're asking for a "complete" tutorial here. I suggest you take a look at NSLayoutConstraints and how to use them programatically. Also, don't add views to the window, but simply to the View in your view controller

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work on iOS 9 or later than the best way to achieve your goal to add subviews next to each other whether it is vertical or horizontal, is to use the UIStackView.

[Class reference of UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/) 
&
[Tutorial of UIStackView](https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views)

Comment: i would like to use the constraints API

Answer (score -1):

You generally should not add views directly to the window. You should almost always have a view controller and you should be adding views to it's content view, not the window.

If you want to place your views side-by-side then you need to add auto-layout constraints to your views and then invoke layoutIfNeeded.

Explaining how to set up constraints is beyond the scope of an SO answer.